# EF how to programmatically apply migrations with multiple DBContexts with different schemas

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For testing purposes i need to programmatically update local db to newest migrations. Problem is that i have 2 DBContexts with different schemas. When i try to use :

```
        var databaseMigrator = new DbMigrator(customMigrationConfiguration);

        databaseMigrator.Update();
```

I have error:

> Automatic migrations that affect the location of the migrations
>   history system table (such as default schema changes) are not
>   supported. Please use code-based migrations for operations that affect
>   the location of the migrations history system table

regards

Comment: You have one DB and two different versions of the same context for this one database? I belive you have to undo migrations from the first database and then exectue the other. Another option would be to copy your db and rename them depending on which context you want to use.

Comment: @user743414 I Have one db with multiple schemas. I dont understand why should i undo migrations?

Comment: You probably need to specify unique names for the migration history table.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman How i can specify it, i cannot find any parameter?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/history-customization / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table